# Accessing Menu Item (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I am using the following code to process clicks on a menu item:

```
 private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;

     switch (mi.Name)
     {
         case "MenuItem1":
         .
         .
         ///How to disable MenuItem2 from here?
         break;

         case "MenuItem2":
         .
         .
         break;
     }
  }
```

While I can access the MenuItem that was clicked, how do I access another MenuItem that wasn't clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use switches on the name property, create an event handler for each item instead. Also if the MenuItem is "static" you should have a reference to it already, so you should be able to use it via `MenuItem2.LoremIpsum`. If it is not static you could add a reference to `MenuItem1` in the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) for example: `Tag="{x:Reference MenuItem2}"`, then you can cast the `mi.Tag` and use it from there. There are of course other methods of aquiring a reference like [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) or other recursive search methods that walk visual or logical trees.

Besides the switching on the name i doubt that accessing one menu item from the other is such a good idea, things will get messy.

Comment: Just realized I am able to access it directly. MenuItem2.IsEnabled = false; actually works. Thanks for the tip about using separate event handlers. The code is not too big so perhaps accessing it from another menu item won't be too troublesome (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Use VisualTreeHelper to go one level up the tree to get to your Menu - from there you can access what you like.